# Does PHP closing tag destructs an instantiated class (object)?

Tags: php, class, tags, instantiation, destructor

```
<?php
  class Student { public $name = "Benjamin"; }
  $name = new Student();
?>

<p>Hello, there. My name is <?php $name->name ?></p>
```

The above code doesn't work as intended (printing the name within "p" tags). But the below code, of course, does work:

```
<?php
class Student { public $name = "Benjamin"; }
$name = new Student();

echo '<p>Hello, there. My name is ' . $name->name . '</p>';
?>
```

---

Is the class being destructed when closing PHP tags?

Is there a work-around for the second code example?

---

Thanks, as always.

Comment: So that I don't comment on every response here, consider this for everyone in particular: "What the hell?! You're right!"

Why hasn't anyone answered "Dumbass" yet? :P

Comment: Maybe because you did not accept any answer and they are scared which one you're going to pick ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your forgot to echo `$name->name`, so your code should look like:

```
<p>Hello, there. My name is <?php echo $name->name ?></p>
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget the `echo` in

```
<p>Hello, there. My name is <?php echo $name->name ?></p>
```

> Is the class being destructed when
>   closing PHP tags?

No

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an echo before $name, so it becomes:

`<?php echo $name->name; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't touched PHP in a long time but,

- no it doesn't
- would `<?php $name->name ?>` really print it?